# Swift Optionals Obnoxiousness

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

Why does the following code fail with a `value of optional type 'Section?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?` compile error?

```
struct Section
{
    let parentID:Int?
    let name:String
}

// sometime later ...

var retrievedSections:[Section]?

// Code to retrieve sections here.

/* Filter out any sections that are not under automation root section. */
if let retSections = retrievedSections
{
    /* Find the root section in the retrieved sections. */
    let rootSections = retSections.filter()
    {
        return ($0).parentID == nil && ($0).name == config.rootSectionName
    }

    if rootSections.count != 1
    {
        print("Invalid root section count!")
    }
    else
    {
        model.rootSection = rootSections[0]
        model.sections = retSections.filter()
        {
            return ($0).isRoot() || ($0).parentID == model.rootSection.id
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about the `($0).parentID`. `parentID` is already marked as optional. Why does it give an error if I compare it with `nil`?

Comment: what's the type of the element in `retrievedSections`? I'm guessing it's `[Section?]`. Which makes total sense. Your `$0` needs unwrapping...

Comment: @Honey [Section]

Comment: AFAIK, that's the only reason. Try restarting your mac/Xcode. If it doesn't work then please share a minimum reproducible code

Comment: @BadmintonCat You sure about that? Because the error you're describing suggests it's actually `[Section?]`...

Comment: What's the type of `config`? Is it `Section` or `Section?`?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Nope it's definitely a [Section].

Comment: Optionals are your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code:-

```
 let retrievedSections = [Section]()
 let rootSections = retrievedSections.filter() {
     return $0.parentID == nil && $0.name == config.rootSectionName
 }
```

Comment: Nope, not the cause of the error. I updated my code above with a more complete, less simplified code. retrievedSections is an array of optionals but in between I evaluate it to a non-optional (retSections).

Comment: @BadmintonCat If it's an array of optionals, it's `[Section?]`, not `[Section]`. Running `if let` on the array won't fix that.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka as you can see above the array is at first optional but not the elements.

Comment: In any case, found the culprit: model.rootSection is optional so it should be `return ($0).isRoot() || ($0).parentID == model.rootSection?.id`

Comment: @BadmintonCat Okay, makes sense. For future reference, next time please be more clear about which line is causing the error. Your description made it look like the error was happening on `return ($0).parentID == nil && ($0).name == config.rootSectionName` (the other line wasn't even there in the original version of your question).

Comment: @CharlesSrstka yes, the compiler first gave me two of the same errors and the first pointed to the previous line. Sometimes I hate the compiler.